# Versions to edit reports

Tags: rdlc, visual-studio-express

Which versions of Microsoft Visual Studio Express can edit `rdlc` files?

I need a free resource for end users to edit the reports to fix cosmetic issues without forcing them to purchase a full VS license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create reports with VS2010 or VS2012 you must consider this fork:
https://github.com/majorsilence/My-FyiReporting

If you create reports with VS2005 or VS2008 you can use this:
http://www.fyireporting.com/ (*)

(*) *EDIT (march 2017): THIS LINK DOESN'T SEEMS TO WORK ANYMORE; SITE WAS COMPLETELY REBUILD AND NOW IT IS ABOUT SEO*

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, especially the active github repo.